# Can we set the iOS notification header time as in iOS Calendar app?

Tags: ios, swift

I've been struggling to find a solution to customize notification header time (Top right corner ) as in iOS calendar; where the notification clearly defines when the event is starting ( in 30 min ) but I didn't find a way to configure it from my end. It shows now when a notification arrives.

[image: Difference between iOS calendar and my custom app notification]

Here in this screenshot above while the notification arrives the ios calendar notification show "in 30 min" and this notification is captured after 15 mins after notification has arrived.

[image: screenshot in the event time]

The above screenshot is captured in the event time. As in the iOS calendar, it shows "**now**" which is correct but in my app notification, the time is calculated from when the notification is arrived instead of event time.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is this still impossible?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is currently no way to customise that text. It will always show the time the notification arrived in the notification center.